# How to provide IIS Basic authentication access without a general user account

Tags: security, iis, windows-server-2012, user-accounts

I want to provide access to my website through IIS Basic auth (already working) but I don't want to give out OS level logins, to my testers/previewers.

Is this possible? How can I do this? I basically just don't want these IIS accounts to be windows accounts. Because then couldn't someone else potentially RDP in with that account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no other way that I know of to use any type of IIS authentication (Basic or Windows Integrated authentication) without a corresponding user account, either locally or in an AD domain that the IIS server is joined to. If you're worried about those users connecting via RDP then make sure they're not in the Remote Desktop Users group.